# Linux search tool for a server

Tags: networking, local-area-network, search, indexing, documents

I would like to search my server (or even the entire local area network) for files with possibility of indexing (even the content of txt, pdf, ... files).
I got suggested this link (https://serverfault.com/questions/4591/recommend-an-opensource-network-search-tool) while starting this question.
Is it any opensource alternative ?
The only other network search tool I know of is google desktop which was not really intended for servers.

Any other suggestion would be appreciated.
Server is Linux debian squeeze 6.0 if that can help.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It's not an end to end tool, but more like a framework. But it's open source and it's made to index almost everything (including content), optimized for quick and flexible search.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like now I know what to do this summer :D

Answer (score 0):

[Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/features.html) is a project that aims to replicate the functionality of OS X's Spotlight on Linux. I think you may be able to attach your own over-the-network interface to it.

Comment: I tried it under Gentoo once for local searches. Didn't really like it much because it didn't work well. Might try to give him a second shot. Thanks.